# How to extract a value from an XML tree

Tags: string-manipulation, json-format

I am trying to pull out a certain value from an XML tree that I have acquired from a website:

```
url = "http://store.nike.com/us/en_us/pd/dry-knit-mens-short-sleeve-running-top/pid-11194817/pgid-11463524";
xmlLarge = Import[url, "XMLObject"];
firstCase = Cases[xmlLarge,
  XMLElement[
   "script", {"id" -> "product-data", "type" -> "template-data"}, {___}], Infinity]
```

The code above returns a fragment of the XML tree that looks something like this:

```
{XMLElement[
  "script", {"id" -> "product-data", "type" -> "template-data"}, {"
               {\"productId\":\"11194817\",\"productGroupId\":\"\
11463524\",\"displayName\":\"Nike Dry Knit Men's Short Sleeve Running \
Top\",\"productTitle\":\"Nike Dry Knit\",\"productSubTitle\":\"Men's \
Short Sleeve Running Top\",\"pageTitle\":\"Nike Dry Knit Men's Short \
Sleeve Running Top. \
Nike.com\",\"catalogId\":\"1\",\"productSlug\":\"dry-knit-mens-short-\
sleeve-running-top\",\"url\":\"http://store.nike.com/us/en_us/pd/dry-\
knit-mens-short-sleeve-running-top/pid-11194817/pgid-11463524\",\"\
startDate\":1481875200000,\"builderUrl\":null,\"frameUtilUrl\":null,\"\
hardLaunch\":false,\"reviews\":{\"averageRating\":4.5,\"\
formattedAverageRating\":\"4.5\",\"ratingRange\":5,\"totalReviewCount\
\":4,"
```

I have copy and pasted only a segment of the XML tree to give a sense of its structure. The code above seems to be returning certain variables and their values ... i.e. `"productTitle":"Nike Dry Knit"`. My goal is to extract the value given the name of the variable, specifically `"totalReviewCount"`, which would return `4`. In the Documentation, it says that `:` means pattern, but the set up also reminds me of `Keys`, so I am a bit confused. Any help and guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Looks like json, but `ImportString[...,"JSON"]` fails for some reason.

Comment: Actually what you call "XML tree" (the third argument of the extracted `XMLElement`) is just an unparsed string...

Comment: `ImportString[firstCase[[1, 3,1]], "JSON"]` does not work, but if one copies it into a JSON validator then it works. And then if you copy it back it also works in Mathematica. Maybe there are hidden characters that get stripped in the copying.

Comment: Whatever you do, don't try to [parse it with a RegEx](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)...

Comment: The failure to import JSON appears to be a bug in the parser.  It does not like the character that appears at position 3393 on the second line, namely the Unicode character _right single quotation mark_.  We can reproduce the bug by evaluating `ImportString["\"\:2019\"", "RawJSON"]`.

Answer (score 9):

So I've figured out how to correctly import json. In my opinion, it's better to explicitly extract such data, field by field. Here you go:

```
firstCase = 
  FirstCase[xmlLarge, 
   XMLElement["script", {"id" -> "product-data", "type" -> "template-data"}, x : ___] :> 
     ImportString[ExportString[x, "Text"], "RawJSON"], , Infinity];

firstCase["reviews", "reviewStatistics", "totalReviewCount"]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this! It worked like a charm

Answer (score 3):

As has been said, `ImportString[..., "JSON"]` does not work. In addition to swish's excellent answer, I discovered dreeve's JSON parser for Mathematica, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2635207/395258). It works:

```
firstCase[[1, 3, 1]] // parseJSON
```

> `{"productId" -> "11194817", "productGroupId" -> "11463524", ...`

You can use `` GeneralUtilities`ToAssociations `` to turn this into an association:

```
assoc = GeneralUtilities`ToAssociations[firstCase[[1, 3, 1]] // parseJSON];
assoc["pageTitle"]
```

> `"Nike Dry Knit Men's Short Sleeve Running Top. Nike.com"`